# Is the usage of "Will" correct in this sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I have a sentence where I already introduced a future hypothesis with "will":

> Future enhancements in Artificial Intelligence **will** bring significant
>   changes in our world, changing the way machines (will) see us.

Is it correct to exclude the second one, that I have put in parenthesis? The thing there's a gerund ("changing") in the mid makes me dubious. Thanks!

Comment: Good question. Up-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the second 'will' is necessary or even possible.
Let me slightly change the sentence to focus on the relevant part:

> *...changing the way machines (**will**) see us.*

means in context:

> *Future enhancements in artificial intelligence **will** change the way machines (**will**) see us.*

What *future enhancements in artificial intelligence will change* is not *the way machines **will** see us* but just *the way machines see us*.

I mean, how can you change something that has yet to happen?

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Indeed there's some unjustified optimism in my sentence, claiming that this fact is inevitable, nevertheless, I have run out of justifications against your claim "how can you change something that has yet to happen?" :-) Thanks!